# Javascript Adding leading zeros works with while loop but not for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm extracting number from a string and passing it to a function. I want to add 1 to it and then return the string while retaining the leading zeros. I was able to do it using a while loop but not a for loop. The for loop simply skips the zeros.

```
var addMoreZeros = (numStr)=> {
    let newNumStr = (parseInt(numStr)+1).toString();
    let zerosToAdd = numStr.length - newNumStr.length;
    let zeroPadStr = "";
    let i = 0;
    while (i < zerosToAdd) {
        zeroPadStr += "0";
        i++;
    }
   //This doesn't work
   //for(let i = 0; i++; i < zerosToAdd) {
   //   zeroPadStr+="0";
   //}
    return zeroPadStr + newNumStr;
}
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < zerosToAdd; i++)`. Also, note that declaring `i` two times is not needed for the `for`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - I assumed the initial `let i = 0;` was part of the `while` solution.

Comment: Ha yes, thanks for pointing that. Yes, I was just testing it in the console.

Comment: FYI: Zero-padding might be done in much simpler [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744576/2118955), without loops.

Comment: @hindmost thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your for loop syntax wrong, it should be:

`(initializer; condition; increments / decrements)`

so:

`for(let i = 0; i < zerosToAdd; i++) {}`

```js
var addMoreZeros = (numStr)=> {
    let newNumStr = (parseInt(numStr)+1).toString();
    let zerosToAdd = numStr.length - newNumStr.length;
    let zeroPadStr = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < zerosToAdd; i++) {
      zeroPadStr+="0";
    }
    return zeroPadStr + newNumStr;
}
console.log(addMoreZeros("00125"))
```

Comment: Fun fact: In the third part of loop syntax you can insert any code (not onyl incrementation or decrementation).
So this code could look like this:
`for(let i = 0; i < zerosToAdd; i++, zeroPadStr+="0") {}`
But please don;t do this, it's unreadable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach (instead of using for/while):

```js
var addMoreZeros = (numStr, numLength = numStr.length) => `${++numStr}`.padStart(numLength,'0');

// example of usage
console.log(addMoreZeros("124", 5));
```

Explanation `++numStr` coerces the numeric string to a number and increments it, then `` `${...}` `` casts the number back to a string. Finally [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) adds leading zeros.

Comment: `(numStr, numLength = numStr.length) => ...` is probably closer to what OP wants. Also this isn't code golf, no need to use cryptic expressions like `((+numStr+1)+'')`. I think `\`${parseInt(numStr) + 1}\`` is a bit more readable there. I didn't downvote, just giving feedback.

Comment: Thanks. We can also use ++numstr here.